# How can I require two - and only two - of four foreign key fields in a model to be filled?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a simple model with two objects. One object type (1) just stores information. The other (2) stores information and connections between objects. The connection can be 1-1, 1-2, or 2-2. Object 2 has four foreign key fields (to and from object 1 & 2). Because a connection can only be made between two objects, I want to specify in my model that not all four foreign keys can be filled in at the same time, but only two in combination. The others should be left blank. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may want to look into [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some validation at the model's level (either directly in the `save` method or using the validation api cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), but this won't be enforced at the database level nor during a `QuerySet.update` operation (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update).